# Creating Buffer on Rectangle with different Requirements

Tags: python, gis, arcmap

I am trying to figure out if Arcmap has a option where it can create a buffer that the north buffer area is different to the south and then have it all in one output.

If it is not possible would python be a alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem or not, but I got an idea about it.
You can split your rectangle polygon into 4 lines. then you should create some field in splitted lines to fill buffer options e.g. buffer range.
If you have many polygons you can split them and buffer all lines with pre-defined fields.

Hope it helps.